# Nav issues with IE11

Tags: css, navigation, internet-explorer-11

I'm running into issues with a nav that I'm creating in IE11. Here's a demo link: http://mikedunlapdesign.com/navDemo/

When the user clicks the nav item the nav shifts over from the left to the right. Behaves fine in FireFox, Chrome, Safari, etc. of course.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following in css will fix this :

```
#header .column{
    transition:none;
    -o-transition:none;
    -webkit-transition:none;
    -moz-transition: none
}
```

Comment: Great I'll check it out later this evening. Thank you for your prompt response.